# Android - Prompting / requesting permissions at startup

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am trying to get a popup requesting the user to grant permissions to access the external storage during startup. I have an activity names Start which is my Launcher activity. Withing this activity I declare some global variables and create some directories if not present. For this I require permissions to the external storage. I have implemented the code as shared on developer.android.com, but it is not granting me the required permissions.

I figured that this is not working because the popup requesting user input is not showing because layout.activity_wait is not visible yet, and I should therefore distribute my code into a AsyncTask such that the layout.activity_wait is visible before calling requestPermissions.

The code below is without the AsyncTask (and yes I am aware of the fact that the App should also be able to work without permissions, I will build that in a later phase :) ). Please let me know what your view is on this. Thanks!

```
public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
    set a bunch of variables to be used in all activities
    **/

    public static ...
    public static ... ...
    public static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wait);

        checkPermission();


        /**
        do some stuff at startup, like creating some directories if not already present
        **/

        launchIntent(this, Home.class); //launch the home screen after initializing all variables and creating directories
        finish();
    }


    private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Start.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("permission", "NOT granted");
             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Start.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }else{
            Log.d("permission", "granted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The permissions request dialog is shown asynchronously. That is, when you call `checkPermission()` and the dialog needs to be shown – i.e., when you don't already have the permission – execution in `onCreate()` is not going to pause while that happens. It will immediately continue, and attempt to do your "stuff" regardless of whether you actually have the permission. You will need to override the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method in the `Activity` to know when the permissions dialog is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mike M. managed to get it working. I did not understand the purpose of onRequestPermissionsResult(). Now I do. See my code below.

```
public class Start extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

        /**
        set a bunch of variables to be used in all activities
        **/

        public static ...
        public static ... ...
        public static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;



        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_wait); //this is a view with a progress bar
            checkPermission();

        }

        private void permissionsGranted() {

                 /**
            do some stuff at startup, like creating some directories if not already present
            **/

            launchIntent(this, Home.class); //launch the home screen after initializing all variables and creating directories
            finish();


        }



        private void checkPermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Start.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // do this if permisisons have not yet been granted
                Log.d("permission", "NOT granted");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Start.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }else{
                // if the permissions have already been granted do the following
                Log.d("permission", "granted");
                permissionsGranted();
            }
        }

        // this is required when ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() is called
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {

                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                       // if permissions have been granted, do the following 
                        permissionsGranted();
                    } else {
                        // possibly prompt why permissions are required and try again
                    }
                    return;
                }

                // other 'case' lines to check for other
                // permissions this app might request.
            }
        }

    }
```